# How do I connect a bootstrap modal submit button to a PUT method in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm currently working on a Task manager system. I want the users to be able to put comments on their assignments as they are doing it in case they have to stop and work on something else, but when they come back they forgot what they were doing with the assignment.

I'm currently working in Node.js with express and a JSONDB because it is a highly portable application that will used.

Here is my Modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="commentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Comments</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="task[comments]" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Comments"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="float:right; inline">Close</button>
            <form action="/progress/<%= progress._id %>/comments?_method=PUT" method="POST">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " style="float: right; inline; margin-right: 2px;">Save changes</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is where it is supposed to connect to:

```
app.put("/progress/:id/comments",function(req,res){
   var query = {
     _id: req.params.id
   };
   var dataToUpdate = {
     comments: req.body.task.comments
   };
   var option = {
     multi: false,
     upsert: false
   };

   db.in_progress.update(query, dataToUpdate, option);
   updateArray();
   res.redirect("/");
});
```

I thought it would be easier for me to do this instead of creating a whole edit page for each individual request because they are simple listings.

When I press the button to submit the comments, nothing occurs.